# Send message to IRC channel using SaltStack

Tags: salt-stack, irc

I have a custom SaltStack event and want to send a message to our IRC when the event occurs. I know how to hook into this event. Question is: How to send a message to our IRC server using SaltStack?

There is an [ircbot engine](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/engines/all/salt.engines.ircbot.html).

The documentation on [engines](https://archive.repo.saltproject.io/en/2019.2/topics/engines/index.html) say:

> Salt Engines are long-running, external system processes that leverage Salt.

This sounds like the tool that I need.

But I did not find an example how to send a message to the ircbot from a Salt State. The examples only show how to send a message to the ircbot from an already logged in IRC user.

Comment: We already have a powershell script to send messages to our IRC. As a workaround, we will use this powershell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ircbot engine` is not currently setup to handle what you are asking for. It is a generic engine that only takes commands and returns results based on that command.

It is mostly used as an example engine for designing your own. So could be updated to a custom engine to do what you are asking about.